# Implementing a synchronization protocol with a UDP Client-Server allowing to change port

Tags: c, sockets, udp, port

I have a UDP Client and Server that I am working with. The basic idea is that I want to have a socket specifically for synchronisation purposes, I want to set up a "3-way handshake" before any actual data is exchanged between the 2 codes.

What I have though of is to create 2 sockets server side, one for synchronization and one for data. Have one socket on the client side and use the synchrnoization messages to change the port of the client socket to link to the data socket on the server side. Once this is all done, technically, both client and server should still be able to communicate however they are intended to. In my case, for now it is simply an echo server.

Here is the two codes:
client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int port_sync, port_data;
    char addr[15];
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Too few arguments given.\n");
        printf("Format: ./client adresseIP port\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (argc > 3)
    {
        printf("Too many arguments given.\n");
        printf("Format: ./client adresseIP port\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(addr, argv[1]);
        port_sync = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    // SYNCHRONIZATION SOCKET

    int socket_sync_fd; 
    socklen_t socket_length;
    struct sockaddr_in server_sync_addr, client_addr;
    memset((char*)&server_sync_addr, 0, sizeof(server_sync_addr));

    if ((socket_sync_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] Connection error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] Client synchronization socket created\n");

    int reuse_sync = 1;
    setsockopt(socket_sync_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_sync, sizeof(reuse_sync));

    server_sync_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_sync_addr.sin_port = htons(port_sync);
    inet_aton(addr, &server_sync_addr.sin_addr);

    // SYNCHRONIZATION

    char syn[BUFFER_SIZE];
    strcpy(syn, "SYN");
    sendto(socket_sync_fd, syn, strlen(syn), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_sync_addr, sizeof(server_sync_addr));
    memset(syn, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    recvfrom(socket_sync_fd, syn, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_sync_addr, &socket_length);
    char delim[] = "-";
    char port[20];
    char *ptr = strtok(syn, delim); // ptr = "SYN"
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);      // ptr = "ACK"
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);      // ptr = port_data
    strcpy(port, ptr);
    port_data = atoi(port);
    printf("new port: %d\n", port_data);
    memset(syn, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    strcpy(syn, "ACK");
    sendto(socket_sync_fd, syn, strlen(syn), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_sync_addr, sizeof(server_sync_addr));
    memset(syn, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    printf("[+] Synchronization successful\n");

    server_sync_addr.sin_port = htons(port_data);

    int recvfrom_return;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while (1)
    {
        printf("UDP Client: ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
        sendto(socket_sync_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_sync_addr, sizeof(server_sync_addr));

        if (strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0)
        {
            close(socket_sync_fd);
            printf("[-] Disconnected from server\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if ((recvfrom_return = recvfrom(socket_sync_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &socket_length)) < 0)
        {
            perror("[-] Data reception error");
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[recvfrom_return] = 0;
            printf("Server: %s\n", buffer);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int port_sync, port_data;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Too few arguments given.\n");
        printf("Format: ./server port_sync port_data\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (argc > 3)
    {
        printf("Too many arguments given.\n");
        printf("Format: ./server port_sync port_data\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        port_sync = atoi(argv[1]);
        port_data = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    // SYNCHRONIZATION SOCKET

    fd_set socket_fd_set;
    FD_ZERO(&socket_fd_set);

    int socket_sync_fd, socket_data_fd; 
    socklen_t socket_length;
    struct sockaddr_in server_sync_addr, server_data_addr, client_addr;
    memset((char*)&server_sync_addr, 0, sizeof(server_sync_addr));

    if ((socket_sync_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] Connection error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] Synchronization socket created.\n");

    server_sync_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_sync_addr.sin_port = htons(port_sync);
    server_sync_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(socket_sync_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_sync_addr, sizeof(server_sync_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] Bind error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] Bind synchronization socket to port %d.\n", port_sync);

    int reuse_sync = 1;
    setsockopt(socket_sync_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_sync, sizeof(reuse_sync));

    int recvfrom_return;
    char buffer[1024];

    while (1)
    {
        FD_SET(socket_sync_fd, &socket_fd_set);
        FD_SET(socket_data_fd, &socket_fd_set);
        int select_return = select(10, &socket_fd_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if(select_return < 0)
        {
            perror("[-] Select error");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(FD_ISSET(socket_sync_fd, &socket_fd_set))
        {
            // SYNCHRONIZATION

            char syn[BUFFER_SIZE];
            char temp[25];
            recvfrom(socket_sync_fd, syn, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &socket_length);
            memset(syn, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

            snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "SYN-ACK-%d", port_data);
            strcpy(syn, temp);
            sendto(socket_sync_fd, syn, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, socket_length);
            memset(syn, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

            recvfrom(socket_sync_fd, syn, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &socket_length);
            memset(syn, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

            printf("[+] Synchronization successful\n");
        }

        if(FD_ISSET(socket_data_fd, &socket_fd_set)){

            if ((socket_data_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
            {
                perror("[-] Connection error");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("[+] Data socket created.\n");

            server_data_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            server_data_addr.sin_port = htons(port_data);
            server_data_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

            if (bind(socket_data_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_data_addr, sizeof(server_data_addr)) < 0)
            {
                perror("[-] Bind error");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("[+] Bind synchronization socket to port %d.\n", port_data);

            int reuse_data = 1;
            setsockopt(socket_data_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_data, sizeof(reuse_data));

            recvfrom_return = recvfrom(socket_data_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &socket_length); 
            if (strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0)
            {
                printf("[-] Disconnected from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
                close(socket_data_fd);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("UDP Client: %s\n", buffer);
                sendto(socket_data_fd, buffer, recvfrom_return, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, socket_length);
                memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            }
        }
    }
    close(socket_sync_fd);
}
```

My issue is that to do this, I know I have to use a select but I haven't been able to use the select correctly in my code to do what I want and I don't know what to do from here.

The basic evolution of the code should be the following:

- Setup socket and sockaddr variables
- Bind them server side
- Client sends "SYN"
- Server responds with "SYN-ACK-5555" where 5555 is the port number for the data socket
- Client gets the new port number and answers with final "ACK"
- Once this is done, the communication between both client and server changes from the initial port to the new one and a basic echo server functionality follows

Ideally, the 3-way handshake and echo functionality are 'independent' and once the handshake is done, the echo part works without ever going back into the handshake part.

This is where the select should be useful as I can split what code is executed based on, which file descriptor is active but I haven't managed to make this work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this another case of trying to mimic TDP using UDP? If you simply provide each client with its own TDP address you can designate processing simply by sending the message to the appropriate address.

Comment: In your server, at the top of your main loop, you [probably] need `FD_ZERO(&socket_fd_set)`. Also, please post these files here in two code blocks. It is against SO guidelines/policy to link to external sites [particularly for code relevant to a question]. Your code will easily fit in in the 30,000 character limit. Many responders will see the linked code and skip trying to answer because it's too much work to use the external site

Comment: @CraigEstey, I attempted this (which I forgot I needed to do so thank you) and found out I have a segmentation fault occurring after the "Bind successful" message. I haven't been able to pin point where this is happening though..